# Why does NBC host Olympic coverage in the USA?

Tags: olympics, media

Living in the USA, NBC (and affiliated networks) has hosted Olympic coverage since I can remember (I think it was CBS at the 1998 Winter Olympics in Nagano).

**Why does NBC host Olympic coverage in the USA?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they paid the most for the rights to show the Olympics.

proof?  [from the June 7, 2011 LA Times:](http://latimesblogs.latimes.com/entertainmentnewsbuzz/2011/06/nbc-holds-onto-olympics-through-2020-with-438-billion-bid.html)

> NBC holds on to Olympics through 2020 with $4.3-billion bid June 7,
>   2011 | 12:20 pm
>
> It is rare that the incumbent is the underdog, but that's what NBC was
>   when it came to holding on to the U.S. television rights for the
>   Olympics.
>
> With rivals Walt Disney Co., owner of ESPN and ABC, and News Corp.,
>   parent of Fox, expected to make aggressive bids for future games and
>   the body language of NBC's new owner, Comcast Corp., indicating a
>   wariness of big-ticket sports events that bleed red ink, the peacock
>   network seemed to be far from a sure thing to remain the home of the
>   Olympic flame.
>
> But when the smoke cleared in Lausanne, Switzerland, it was NBC that
>   walked away with the rights to the Olympics through 2020. The price
>   tag for the four games is $4.38 billion. The breakdown is as follows:
>   The 2014 Winter Games in Sochi, Russia, will cost $775 million. The
>   2016 Summer Games in Rio de Janeiro will cost $1.2 billion. The 2018
>   Games will run $863 million, and the 2020 Games will cost $1.4
>   billion. The locales for the 2018 and 2020 games have not been
>   determined yet.
>
> Comcast Chief Executive Brian Roberts, who traveled to Lausanne with
>   the NBC team for the presentation and bid, said, "I absolutely wanted
>   to win for the team."

Comment: If that is the case, do you have evidence of it being so?

Comment: @Nicholas V. How's that, then?